# Have I turned my system into a FrankenDebian?

Tags: debian

I was trying to fix the computer of a colleague.

The main /etc/apt/sources.list had entries pointing  to ***debian buster*** which is ***Debian 10***.

Later I saw, /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ had a file called teams.list, which had this entry:

`deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main`

Now stable currently points to ***Debian 11***.

I did :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and then I did :

```
sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb
```

(this is what I was trying to do - update zoom).

My query is : Have I turned this computer into a [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian)?

How can I find out if all is ok ? What should I be doing ?

I think that ms-teams ***did not update*** and hence I am safe, but I wish to confirm.

Comment: `stable` for some MS repo != `stable` for Debian repos.

Comment: Does that mean that I am safe?

Comment: When you did the `apt-get upgrade` did it proceed to update a zillion packages?  If not, you probably did not accidentally do a full or partial distribution upgrade.

Comment: If I remember correctly, around 400 MB of disk space was used on doing `apt-get upgrade`. I wish there was a methodical way of figuring this out.

Comment: Read `/var/log/dpkg.log` and its compressed older versions. It should have a line of the form `<timestamp> upgrade <package-name> <old-version> <new-version>` for each package upgrade. With that, you should be able to see exactly what packages were updated and what versions did they have before the update.

Comment: Hi, I used the chat help in learn.microsoft.com. It said that the packages.microsoft.com (stable) repository which is being used is meant for ***both*** Debian 10 ***and*** 11. Would I be correct in thinking that my Debian is safe even though teams ***was upgraded*** (which I saw in the dpkg logs)?

Comment: ```$ cat /var/log/dpkg.log.1  | grep upgrade  | wc -l
163
``` In words, 163 packages were upgraded. Any comments on that ?